# JQuery - Selecting by class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to this and I've just started writing things by myself, and I have a small problem, selecting by class doesn't work for me. I use TamperMonkey to write search phrase into Google Search (www.gooogle.com).
Getting that element by ID works fine:

```
$("#lst-ib").val("Something");
```

But getting it by class just doesn't work:

```
$(".gsfi").val("Something");
```

I tried adding code to make it run after DOM is ready, so now it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gsfi").val("Something");
});
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Please show up the HTML Code..

Comment: A simple check you could do is to write the following line: `console.log($('.gsfi').length());` which will return the number of the elements containing this class. If the value returned is 0, there isn't such a class there.

Comment: if they are divs that you are updating change val to html you will see the change...$('.gsfi').html("something")

Comment: How I said, I wanted to add string to Google Search Box.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it there should not be any chance of issues. If you set the value of an element it should happen. If you are thinking that setting the value of an element will change the text of that div, its wrong. Setting the value of an HTML element will not change the content of div. For that you need to set the text of the div. I have attached a sample code snippet for setting the value of an element and changing the text of an element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").val("Value1");
    $("#test").val("Value2");
});

function alertvalues(){
 console.log($(".test").val());
    console.log($("#test").val());
}

function changetext(){
 $(".test").text("Changed Content 1");
    $("#test").text("Changed Content 2");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="test">Sample text 1</div>
<div id="test">Sample text 2</div>
<button onclick="alertvalues()">Log Values</button>
<button onclick="changetext()">Change Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```